# Geometric transformations

Tags: c++, performance, math, geometry

The task is to when we have a line segment in 3 dementional space (we have coordinate of both ends) and we have informations as `angle`, `ratio` and `amount`. Our job is to give us next few line segments (few=`amount`) which have their start in end of our first line segment (we know which is the end and the start of this line) and are rotated as here

[image: rotated as here]

And top view at our first line (line is in the center (this black point)):

[image: And top view at our first line]
`Amount` is up to 100. `Angle` to 180*.

That is what I've done:

Sx,Sy,Sz - Start coord
x,y,z - end coords

```
float siny=sqrt((x-Sx)*(x-Sx)+(z-Sz)*(z-Sz))/S->korona[lvl-1]->l;
            float cosy=(y-Sy)/S->korona[lvl-1]->l;
            float cosx=(Sx-x)/sqrt((x-Sx)*(x-Sx)+(z-Sz)*(z-Sz));
            float sinx=(z-Sz)/sqrt((x-Sx)*(x-Sx)+(z-Sz)*(z-Sz));
            float co=cos(angle);
            float si=sin(angle);
            float newa=a*ratio;
            for(int j=0;j<S->amount;j++){
                float a=newa*(co*cos(360.0f/S->amount*j*rad)*cosy-si*siny);
                float b=newa*(co*cos(360.0f/S->amount*j*rad)*siny+si*cosy);
                float c=newa*co*sin(360.0f/S->amount*j*rad);
}
```

Our new:

```
x=c*sinx+a*cosx+S->korona[lvl-1]->sticks[i]->x
y=b+S->korona[lvl-1]->sticks[i]->y
z=c*cosx-a*sinx+S->korona[lvl-1]->sticks[i]->z)
```

How to get this faster? This solution is bad by the way. Is there better way?

Something like **[HERE](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5vSaRMzyurE)** but in **3D**

Comment: ...and your programming question is?

Comment: That's algorithm. It;s a part of programming

Comment: So you want someone to do your homework without you even trying anything? Good luck with that!

Comment: I tried. I have something. Wait, i will paste it

Comment: Ok, there is it. But i dont thinkt it will help. I dont want others to suggest

Comment: Well done: now you have a reasonable SO question!

Comment: Thanks :) I'm not sleeping because of this :p Rly. Added also a link to youtube at the end.

Comment: What makes you think it's (too) slow? How much faster do you need it? There are some values that are calculated multiple times in your loop, and there are some clever tricks about sin/cos relationships that can sometimmes be used, but I'm not sure any of those would really help here.

Comment: It's not very slow. But i need **everything** to improve that. Cuc im doing it incredibly often. Evry 0.0000001s is good for me. And I remind that this code is wrong.

Comment: Use a quaternion. There are plenty of free quaternion implementations out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a more elegant way. There is only one thing you really need to know: the definition of cosine in terms of inner products, which holds in any dimension. Given vectors u and v the cosine of the angle between them is:

( u^t v)/( |u| |v| ).

Start by using a unit vector u=(1,0,0). This eliminates the denominator of the formula. 
Now you can get a unit vector v whose angle with u matches your parameter: v=(cos \theta, sin \theta, 0).

Next rotate v about u (the x axis) by 360/Amount using [these rotation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions) (amount -1) times.

Now you have all the vectors you need. All you have left to do is:

1. Rotate them so that the original unit vector is "aligned" with the difference vector between your original points (the same Wikipedia page has the matrix for that too), and
2. Translate them to the whichever of the original points you wanted to be the origin by adding that point to each vector.

Personally, I would go the public library and find an introductory linear algebra book. Gilbert Strang's is my favorite. The Wikipedia content is very nice and complete, but over time it has become a bit overwhelming for people who don't already have some expertise. All of this material is explained very nicely in any of these books with many examples, right in the first chapter or two.

As for the programming part of it: if all you need to implement is dense 3x3 matrix products, I'd just do it directly instead of incorporating a library. On the other hand, you may soon find yourself inverting matrices, and that can get a bit tricky in practice. How much more geometry you need should be the main factor in deciding whether incorporating a 3rd party library is worth the trouble.